# RSpec with CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, circleci

I've been writing mock test with RSpec.
The problem is the end point I specified doesn't seem to accept the POST request within CircleCI container.
(The test works fine locally.)

[image]

In `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Handle Stripe Webhooks
  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at:'/stripe-events'
```

Comment: What is '/stripe-hogehoge'?

Comment: This is the endpoint for failure case. It should return 404.